# Pandas conditional division, series by list

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, division

I'm trying to apply an if condition to a pandas series and subsequently apply a division operation to another series in the same dataframe against an integer value from a list.

The logic I'm trying to apply is as follows: If the household category in the `hh_cat` series matches the current value of `i` then divide the consumption series by the relevant total of the family consumption sub-group given by the list value `family_con[i-1]`.

```
for i in hh_cat:
   result = mod_df[(mod_df["hh_cat"]==i)].div()["consumption"](family_con[i-1])
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-219bc0ce5a07> in <module>()
  1 for i in hh_cat:
----> 2     result = mod_df[(mod_df["hh_cat"]==i)].div()["consumption"] (family_con[i-1])

TypeError: f() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: untested but maybe try `mod_df[(mod_df["hh_cat"]==i)]["consumption"].div(family_con[i-1])`

Comment: more of the stacktrace would help, what is `f`?

Comment: first suggestion fixes the error but I am trying to find a way to pass the results to a new series that will be added to the dataframe. I'm not sure if the loop is the best way to do this but I've passed the results of the division to a list which retains the correct values but with a varying index given the operation is performed on different rows for different values of i. I suppose I could resort the list according to the index number of the rows but it seems to be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using merge might help:

First convert the list to a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(family_con,columns=['cons'])
```

Next add a column to your original data frame which matches the index and can be used to join:

```
mod_df["hh_cat_join"]= mod_df["hh_cat"]-1
```

Next perform the join:

```
merged_df=mod_df.merge(df,how='left',left_on='hh_cat_join',right_index=True)
```

Finally do the calculation and save it in result column:

```
merged_df['result']=merged_df['consumption']/merged_df['cons']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of the connection between the variable `hh_cat` and the column `'hh_cat'`, but I think you could add a column called `hh_cat_var` (corresponding to the variable you're iterating through) and do

```
mod_df[mod_df['hh_cat'] == mod_df['hh_cat_var']]....
```